# Test whether each element in the string is in 8 bit format using regex

Tags: regex

I have a string which consists most of 0s or 1s. I need to check whether each element in the string is in 8 bit format delimited by the space except for the last element.

For example:

**These strings should return true**

- `"11001100 01101111 11001011 00001011"` // true
- `"00001100 11101111 11001000 00000001 11001011"` // true

**And these strings should return false**

- `"11001100 1100101 01101111"` // false because the second element is only 7bit
- `"11001100 01101111 11001011 00200011"` // false because there is 2 in the last element

I have tried this code but all of the test return true. I am new to regex so any help would be much appreciated :)

```
console.log(/([01]{8})+\s?/.test(str2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closed, use:

```
/^[01]{8}(?: [01]{8})*$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
  ^             : beginning of string
    [01]{8}     : 0 or 1, must appear 8 times
    (?:         : start non capture group
                : 1 horizontal space
      [01]{8}   : 0 or 1, must appear 8 times
    )*          : end group, must appear 0 or more times
  $             : end of line
/               : regex delimiter
```

```js
var test = [
    "11001100 01101111 11001011 00001011",
    "00001100 11101111 11001000 00000001 11001011",
    "11001100 1100101 01101111",
    "11001100 01101111 11001011 00200011"
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' --> '+/^[01]{8}(?: [01]{8})*$/.test(a);
}));
```

Comment: Your code returns false on the first string which should be true.

Comment: @Joven28: My bad, js doesn't recognize `\h`, fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Btw I am wondering why the expression ?: should be added?

Comment: @Joven28: This is a non capture group, more efficient than capture group when it is not needed.